# Drop Down Menu with Sub Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, jmenuitem

I am working on a project and I'm struggling with one piece. It may be very simple, but I'm clearly over looking something. My objective is to have a menu and sub-menu populate on a hover over a specific image. When you hover over the image you'll see "categories" and to the right see the "sub-menu" to that category. I am able to get the first category to work, but unable to get any of the subsequent categories to change the "sub-menu" to the right. I've included the code below. Any help would be appreciated - I'm struggling to make this work

Menu Example:
[image: Menu Example]

This is my styling css:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../images/Framework-and-Navigation_03.png);
    min-width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2{
display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
        color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown-content3{
display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
        color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content-sub1 {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content-sub2 {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-content-sub3 {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}



/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: inline-block;}

/* Change the sub menu */
.dropdown-content1:hover .dropdown-content-sub1 {display: block;}

.dropdown-content2:hover .dropdown-content-sub2 {display: inline-block;}
```

This is my menu/submenu test:

```
<div class="dropdown">
      <center>
        <input type="image" class="dropbtn" src="images/menu_07.png"/>
      </center>
<div class="dropdown-content">
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="158">    
         <div class="dropdown-content1"><a href="">Link 1</a></div>
         <div><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
         <div><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>   
      </td>
      <td class="dropdown-content-sub1" valign="top"><div>
         <a href="#">Test</a>
         </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this solves your problem :)

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
html,
body {
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.menu-container {
  width: 615px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #eee url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538098269808-2ace9a4d9680?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=2a48defb8057de5b3f79b49b85c173bc&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60") no-repeat 200px 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

ul.menu,
ul.menu ul {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ul.menu li,
ul.menu ul li {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
ul.menu li a,
ul.menu ul li a {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
ul.menu li:hover ul,
ul.menu ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 0 0 200px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.nav {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.nav > .nav-item {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.nav > .nav-item:hover > .menu-container,
.nav > .nav-item:hover > .menu-container > .menu {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-item" href="">Nav item 1
    <div class="menu-container">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Menu item 1 ></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub menu 1 item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub menu 2 item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Menu item 3 ></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Sub menu 2 item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Sub menu 2 item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item" href="">Nav item 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't resolve the issue I'm experiencing. I'm trying to have the sub menu pop down so it doesn't extend the image that it is sitting on, and also to have the submenu's to the right all line up to the top. I'm going to attach a screen shot of what I have, but again the content to the right is what I can't get to change.

Comment: Added the image to under Menu Example in original post

Comment: thank you for your support! I tweaked the code to fit my need, but what you provided seriously helped me get there! Thank you again!